# Two buttons of equal width but stretch to the width of the parent when one is GONE - Android

Tags: android, xml, layout

This should be pretty simple but I'm really stuck. 
So here's my layout:

```
 __________________________
 | layout                 | 
 |[Button A ] [ Button B ]|
 |________________________|
```

And then when you make Button A Visibility.GONE I need this:

```
 __________________________
 | layout                 | 
 |[      Button B        ]|
 |________________________|
```

or Button B Visibility.GONE:

```
 __________________________
 | layout                 | 
 |[      Button A        ]|
 |________________________|
```

I have tried *everything*. Any sort of layout will do, it doesn't have to be Relative or Linear or anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can whoever downvoted this please explain? It's a valid question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, with Linear Layout set the weight of each View  to 1, orientation horizontal. Don't set a `weightSum`!
You can set the visibility to gone in xml or by `myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="de.project.amy.amyatanim.DataFragment">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button 2" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Was a little tricky with RelativeLayout. Here, you have to set the space and the button4 visibility to gone, and also set the width of button 5 to match parent, all programmatically, but not impossible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button4"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/space"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button5"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/space"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The Views with the **same** weights in a LinearLayout divide the space equally between them - so if one is gone, the other can take up the whole space. You could also try different weights & more Views, it'll work. Since no weightSum is set, the LinearLayout will not 'fill' the space a 'gone' View has left.

Comment: Ahh OK, so since the only view there has a weight of 1, it'll fill the space, but when there are n views with a weight of n, it just acts like the weightSum is n. Make sense!

Comment: I think there is also a way to do this with a relative Layout, I'll try this out now x)